# How to specify color properties (fill and stroke) of a path in JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, photoshop-script

So I'm trying to optimize some designs in my process, for this task I'm experimenting with javascripts for Illustrator and Photoshop, the issue i have right now is that for drawing, filling and changing the stroke color of my paths. So how I can an array of colors in JS for Illustrator to fill a path of one color and the stroke of another color?

Right know it just take my last declared CMYK color and ignores previous ones.

Code:

```
var RectangleColor = new CMYKColor();
RectangleColor.black = 0;
RectangleColor.cyan = 0;
RectangleColor.magenta = 0;
RectangleColor.yellow = 0;

var RectangleColorStroke = new CMYKColor();
RectangleColor.black = 0;
RectangleColor.cyan = 80;
RectangleColor.magenta = 80;
RectangleColor.yellow = 0;
```

and in the drawing method

```
rect.filled = true;
rect.fillColor = RectangleColor;
rect.strokeColor = RectangleColorStroke;
```

Note: I don't really know if exist a property named `strokeColor`, but since it didn't show any error then was decided to use it.

Comment: It won't show any errors because you're not asking, but  setting a prop. Check Illustrator Scripting References pdf for more info. Also note that for Photoshop the code will be completely different

Answer (score 0):

Well i know is not the most clean way but already found how.

declared this variable

```
  var col = new GrayColor();
  col.gray = 100;
```

have this at the code

```
var rect = artLayer.pathItems.rectangle (monthsCubeY,monthsCubeX,180,100); //draw rectangle at the selected coordenates
                    monthsCubeX = monthsCubeX + 190; //move the coordenates for the next rectangle
 rect.filled = true; 
 rect.stroked = true; 
 strokeWidth = 1;
 rect.fillColor = RectangleColor;
 strokeColor = col;
```

I dont know much of coding, but this seems to work for me.